# Functional interface instantiation using Lambda-Compilation error- Lambda expression is not expected here only in command prompt

Tags: lambda, java-8, compiler-errors

I have written functional interface and tried to instantiate it using Lambda expression and I am able to compile and run it successfully in eclipse , But when I tried to compile it using "javac" in command prompt, it is getting failed with error "lambda expression not expected here" pointing to my lambda expression and "can not find symbol" pointing to functional interface.

I am able to compile this and run in Eclipse using java 8.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CalcInterface{

Integer addNumbers(int x, int y);

}

/*Able to compile this functional interface mentioned above
* using javac CalcInterface.java
*/

//functional interface impl here, in the same package
public class FuncInterfaceImpl{

public static void main(String[] args){

    CalcInterface calc=(n1,n2) -> n1+n2;
     System.out.println(calc.addNumbers(10,20));

}

}

javac FuncInterfaceImpl.java 
Result: compilation error lambda expression not expected here , can not find symbol CalcInterface 


I expected successful compilation and output 30 when I run it using java.
```

Comment: *I am able to compile this and run in Eclipse using java 8* vs *Able to compile this functional interface mentioned above using javac*. so which one is it? but, either way - it's an `ecj` problem

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to know about your `CalcInterface` when you only run `javac FuncInterfaceImpl.java`? You have to specify either, a source path pointing to the location of `CalcInterface.java` or a class path pointing to the location of the compiled `CalcInterface.class`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Both the functional interface and this class are in the same package.I have tried by setting the class path also like the below.  javac -classpath <drectory of CaclInterface.class file> FuncInterfaceImpl.java , But still it is not able to compile successfully.